# Cheerio selector returns blank array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

Try to get names of mathes in "Starting soon" section of this web-site: https://favbet.com/en/bets/

This is my code:

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');
    matches = [];

request('https://favbet.com/en/bets/', function (err, resp, body) {
  if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var content = $('#startsoon').find('li.col20').each(function() {
      var match = this.text();
      matches.push(match);
    });
    console.log(matches);
  }
});
```

Console.log returns blank array. I'm not quite understand how the deep nesting works in this case.

Comment: The "startsoon" table is created dynamically by a script `startingsoon.js` which first loads JSON data from the server. You'll need to use a scrapping engine which can execute scripts on the page and wait for the results

Comment: Maybe this is the json that you are looking for - https://favbet.com/bets/starting_soon/. No need screen scrapping. :)

Comment: haha, thank you) How you find it?

Comment: Please be careful when using this in consideration to usage rights. You are probably not allowed to show case data from this json on your web page.

Comment: ok, I will read terms and conditions before use it in my code